# Eggplant Functional comparing a value in csv to an readtext of image

Tags: eggplant

I am trying to complete foundation certification and on lesson 5 I needed help to complete the exercise.

I know how to read a csv (myResults)
put fourth item of line 2 of myResults into color

say color value = purple

I need to select the matching radio button ( Purple, Orange, Yellow)

ReadText("Purple"), ReadText("Yellow") or ReadText("Orange")

Click allows web element, image, text, characters but not a variable. How do I do that? Need to select the correct radio button based on value in csv.

Comment: How are you locating the 3 buttons? Are you using images? Are you looking for a text string?

Comment: using images, however it frequently complains image not found within time even after a wait

Comment: One problem at a time. Are you trying to go from a color name in a CSV to clicking a radio button matching that color, using a pre-captured image to locate the radio button?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: Are you having selecting the 4th item of line two of the CSV or are you having trouble clicking the image associated with the value you are getting from the CSV?

Comment: selecting the appropriate image

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to clarify the specifics of your question? It will help other people in the future seeking help with similar problems.

Comment: Done. I hope I am clear. Also wondering why you are setting value from csv to purple? Not sure I follow that

Comment: Purple is just an arbitrary color value. In your actual code it would be whatever value you got from the CSV.

Comment: I'd suggest rolling back your edit since it looks like you're asking a different question about failing to find images. Questions on this site should focus on one and only one thing. If you are having difficulties clicking on images when you hard code the desired image it might be a good idea to ask that question separately. It helps when asking questions to include a [minimal, complete, verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are facing. This makes it easier for people to understand your situation, and to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks I have added the if else esleif like was suggested. I will post a separate question regarding the next hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Eggplant Functional](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-mouse-events-control.htm#click-command) is confusing at the best of times but it is possible to identify the image you want to click using a variable containing a string. The click command takes a parameter called an [image reference](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/using/epf-image-references.htm) which can be an image name, image collection, image property list, or character collection. It doesn't matter to click whether the image reference is passed as a variable or as a hard coded value.

You need to create a mapping between the string you extract from the CSV and the name of the image you are wanting to click. There are many ways you could do this but one solution would be to switch on the value you extracted from the CSV and define a variable with the name if the button you want to click based on that value.

Say for the sake of argument the values you are getting from your CSV are in the form `"prpl"`, `"ylwo"`, and `"orng"`, and the names of the images you are wanting to click are `"purpleButton.png"`, `"yellowButton.png"`, and `"orangeButton.png"`. If this case the code to click the correct button would look something like this.

```
// In your actual code this value would be set from CSV
set valueFromCSV to "prpl"

if valueFromCSV is equal to "prple"
    set buttonToClick to "purpleButton.png"
else if valueFromCSV is equal to "ylwo"
    set buttonToClick to "yellowButton.png"
else if valueFromCSV is equal to "orng"
    Set buttonToClick to "orangeButton.png"
else
    error("Unable to identify color code from CSV")
end if

click buttonToClick
```

If you are working with a consistently designed CSV, and consistently named images it could be possible to construct the image names by manipulating the values you are extracting from the csv. For instance if the values you are getting from the CSV are `"purple"`, `"yellow"`, and `"orange"`, and the images are named `"purpleButton.png"`, `"yellowButton.png"`, and `"orangeButton.png"`, you could construct the names of the buttons with logic like this.

```
// In your actual code this value would be set from CSV
set valueFromCSV to "purple"

set buttonToClick to valueFromCSV & "Button.png"

click buttonToClick
```